# EXC_BAD_ACCESS during in app purchase test

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase, storekit

Running a test for my in app purchase (first time doing in app purchases). I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the third line of this code:

```
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:electronicProd];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

The is under an IBAction for a button. electronicPack is declared in the header as a SKProduct. Threw some NSLogs in the productsRequest didReceiveResponse, and when the product was requested (in the viewDidLoad) and they showed it was correctly fetching the product and storing it in electronicPack. Defined electronicPack as [[request.products] objectAtIndex:0] in the didReceiveResponse page. So yea. Thats where im at, dont know what to do. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: FIXED accidentally left in code that was adding an extra transaction observer lol

Comment: In the electronicProd definition, did you call the retain message? Every event is wrapped in an autorelease pool, if you instantiated your object with it's static init method, the item will be released once the viewDidLoad method is over.

Comment: are you asking if i did like:

electronicPack = [SKProduct alloc] init]

? the answer to that is no. If thats not what youre asking then im not sure what youre saying, im a little new to this ballgame. lol

Comment: Im not too good with the whole memory management, property stuff. and all that. Have only been programming for around a month and havent quite picked that up yet. Ill give that a try tho and see if it fixes anything

EDIT: Implemented the self.elec..etc stuff and no change. still getting error

Comment: when the app crashes, type t a a bt (thread apply all bt) in the gdb window and tell us what you come up with

Comment: Ok, so you are using the static methods, I'll reply so it's more clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to retain the object that you are creating

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   //... stuff
   SKProduct* electronicProduct = //...
   [electronicProduct retain];
   //... otherstuff
}
```

viewDidLoad is wrapped by the system in a autorelease pool, paymentWithProduct: returns an autorelease object. When viewDidLoad is done, all autorelease object are released, that's why you get a bad memory access when you try to access to it later.

Answer (score 40):

I've had the same issue, my solution was to call

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
```

on leaving the In-App Store in my App.
Maybe it will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 26):

Seems like the issue is from trying to add a transaction observer before removing the previous one. Add the following to your controller to fix this issue:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This was the answer for me. Still valid with Xcode 6.3 and iOS 8.3

Comment: Excellent, thanks!! For me this also worked, using the code from Mihael Isaev (below) and putting it into ViewDidDisappear.

Answer (score 12):

Mr.T answer is the best solution!

In swift I call this removeTransactionObserver here:

```
deinit {
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: Where do you do the deinit!? the appdelegate file!?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, quite simple to solve really. In my header file I had a SKProduct declared:

```
@property SKProduct *product;
```

I just changed it to:

```
@property (retain) SKProduct *product;
```

and it all works fine.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a dedicated class for `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` don't forget that it must be retained.

I got the error before realizing this, here's an example in `AppDelegate`:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var myTransactionObserver: MyTransactionObserver!


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // don't
        let myTransactionObserver = MyTransactionObserver()

        // do
        myTransactionObserver = MyTransactionObserver()

        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(myTransactionObserver)

        return true
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Have the same issue, my solution was to call
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];

on store observer transaction finish/failed/completed callbacks